# Android Browser ignores position:absolute

Tags: android, html, css, position, absolute

I'm developing a mobile website for kids, but I'm struggling with android tablets. Problem being is, that the footer is not docked to the bottom.

This is the website on any browser (Desktop) and iPad:

[image]

and this is the website on our android device (Android 4.2.2):

[image]

HTML snippet:

```
<div id="wrapper" class="... stuff ...">
  <div class="center">
    <div id="content"> 
      ... content stuff omitted ...
      <footer id="footer"> 
        <img src="img/bg.svg" alt="" width="100%"> <!-- Footer image -->
        <img src="img/marienkaefer.png" alt="marienkaefer" id="marienkaefer" width="26"> <!-- Flying ladybug relative to the footer -->
        <img src="img/schmetterling.png" alt="schmetterling" id="schmetterling" width="20"> <!-- Flying butterfly relative to the footer -->
      </footer>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

The CSS snippet:

```
#wrapper {
  width:100%;
  height:100%;
  min-width:1024px;
  display:table;
}
.center{
  display:table-cell;
  width:100%;
  height:100%;
  vertical-align:middle;
  text-align:center;
}
#content{
  width:1024px;
  height:652px;
  margin:0 auto;
  position:relative;
  z-index:20;
  overflow:hidden;
  background: url(../img/blurBG.jpg) no-repeat 100% 100% / cover transparent;
}
#footer{
  width: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
}
#footer img{
  float:left;
}
```

Any suggestions why this won't work on android?

Comment: maybe your browser doesn't support html5. use div instead of footer tag.

Comment: Replaced the footer with div, but no change.